# Evaluating a determinant with multiple variables and multiplicative inverses

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers, determinant, complex-geometry

I just asked a question on math stack exchange and doing some progress on it: [Proof of Pascal's Theorem (on circles) using complex numbers.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3275908/proof-of-pascals-theorem-on-circles-using-complex-numbers).

I did some complex number geometry, got the intersection points and now all it remains is to evaluate a determinant which *should* evaluate to zero.

Here's the determinant:

$$
   \frac{i}{4} \begin{vmatrix}
    \frac{ab(d+e) - de(a+b)}{ab-de} & \frac{\frac{1}{ab}(\frac 1d+\frac1e) - \frac{1}{de}(\frac1a+\frac1b)}{\frac{1}{ab}-\frac{1}{de}} & 1 \\
    \frac{bc(e+f) - ef(b+c)}{bc-ef} & \frac{\frac{1}{bc}(\frac1e+\frac1f) - \frac{1}{ef}(\frac1b+\frac1c)}{\frac{1}{bc}-\frac{1}{ef}} & 1 \\
    \frac{cd(f+a) - fa(c+d)}{cd-fa} & \frac{\frac{1}{cd}(\frac1f+\frac1a) - \frac{1}{fa}(\frac1c+\frac1d)}{\frac{1}{cd}-\frac{1}{fa}} & 1 \\
    \end{vmatrix}
$$
where $a, b, c, d, e, f$ are points $A, B, C, D, E, F$ on the unit circle.

I don't want to evaluate this by straight up multiplication and minors. Please explain how to solve this determinant using its properties.

Thanks!

Comment: Helping to edit this post: see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/5023#5023).  Please implement this yourself, it is very easy to understand.

Comment: You can simplify it greatly by (i) in the $(1,2)$ entry multiplying top and bottom by $abde$ [I am assuming there is a typo and the $c$ on top are really $e$] (ii) same for other entries in second column (iii) multiply top row by $ab-de$, keeping track of the factor.

Comment: I am not getting the hang of what you are saying. Can you please explain a bit in detail? Thanks! PS: I am not that experienced in determinants.

Comment: Multiply the numerator and the denominator of the entry in the first row and second column by $abde$. Multiply the numerator and the denominator of the entry in the first row and third column by $ab-de$. You can then take out a factor $\frac{1}{ab-de}$ from the first row. Repeat for each row. The determinant left is much simpler.

Comment: OK. But how do you move further? Thanks for helping till now!

Answer (score 1):

*(This is only a comment. It is placed here so that the others can copy the matrices below easily.)*

Your matrix is equal to
$$
\frac{i}{4}\pmatrix{\frac{1}{ab-de}\\ &\frac{1}{bc-ef}\\ &&\frac{1}{cd-fa}}
\pmatrix{
ab(d+e)-de(a+b) &(a+b)-(d+e) &ab-de\\
bc(e+f)-ef(b+c) &(b+c)-(e+f) &bc-ef\\
cd(f+a)-fa(c+d) &(c+d)-(f+a) &cd-fa}.
$$
It suffices to prove that the rightmost matrix in the above is singular.